# Delete the url of the image but the image don't delete

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My problem is that I add the URL to the image correctly but when I'm trying to delete it...

```
 public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        article article = db.articles.Find(id);
        db.articles.Remove(article);  
        db.SaveChanges();
        var a = db.image.Where(r => r.articleid == id); 
        foreach (var b in a)
        {
            string location = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(b.url));
            System.IO.File.Delete(location);
           article.images.Remove(b);


        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: "delete the url"? don't you mean "filesystem path"? a filesystem IO operation won't know what to do with `http://example.com/foo/bar/kittens.jpg`.

Comment: did u trying stepping through the code with the debugger, i am sure it will be obvious

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess, but the first `db.SaveChanges();` removes the article from the database, so could that also have cascaded and removed the related image references before you pull out the ids needed to remove the files?

Try removing the first `db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: sir my problem not with deleting the boject my problem with th i/o

Answer (score 0):

You need delete images first, and then delete task. Or use cascade in your table.

Comment: can you give me an example on cascade please

Answer (score 0):

```
  it should be
```

db.image.Remove(b);

```
 instead of
```

article.image.remove(b)

Comment: Sir i'm really sorry but maybe you did not understand what i mean,,,, i post my answer just for if anyone have the same problem he'll find the answer 
anyway thanks for helping me and sorry again if there is misunderstanding